# Problem Saving Installation of nvm, npm Linux

Tags: linux, npm, installation, terminal, nvm

I am new to front-end programming, and have been trying to set up a react environment on my Chromebook/Linux Machine. I managed to get nvm, node, and npm installed as well as a template react app created. But when I exed out of the terminal and then created a new terminal window, I was unable to access these installations. Installing the packages again seemed to work, but there has got to be a way for them to save between uses of the terminal. What is going wrong?

Things to note:

I added the bash source completion string after the first (and subsequent) installations.

During the later installations it did tell me that nvm was already installed and gave a location of the directory. This did not help me as I was unable to find it in that location or confirm that it had installed via -V after creating a new terminal window.

Screenshots:

[Re-installed nvm, says it was already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RG4S.png)

[Seems like NVM is in my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4XM8.png)

[Still Can't Access NVM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VGp8.png)

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Please provide more detail. write the error and also put screenshots.

Comment: I added some screenshots to my post!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the export within the shell that you use. You most probably use zsh. Check with `echo $SHELL` and based on that update the rc file. In your case add the following in  `.zshrc`

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

and open a new tab or do `source .zshrc` and try again.